# How do I get content to overflow into another div if there is room, using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a main content area and a right column content area. The content in the right column is usually short. 
How do i make the content from the main content area overflow into the right if there is no content there.

**CSS**

```
#left {
    width: 440px;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border-left: 1px;
}
```

Comment: would you please provide your html?

Comment: When you say "overflow", do you mean like a long paragraph of text that continues in the next column? Or do you mean like a large piece of content that is increased in width to cover both columns (which, techically speaking is a collapsing column)? The two will lead to entirely different answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logic**

Getting content to flow into another container IF the other container is empty -- that's logic. There's no mechanism for logic in CSS. You'd have to have at least some JavaScript, or some server-side logic (conditionally changing the static HTML sent by the server).

If the other container is empty, the logic in JavaScript (or on the server-side) could change the layout to one that allows the content to flow. How that flow would happen, and if it's possible with CSS alone, is a separate matter. This is just addressing the related logic first.

**Content flow**

Getting the content to flow into another container would be very difficult to do with CSS alone. Generally speaking, that's not how content flows in browsers. I think the closest you could reasonably get would be using [CSS3 Columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/), but they're not supported by IE9 or earlier. More importantly, the current standard doesn't support using [columns of different widths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#the-multi-column-model). So that seems to rule out CSS3 Columns already.

It seems likely that the only option for the content flow is to break up the content into appropriate-size pieces, either by JavaScript or on the server-side, and place the content pieces in the appropriate columns.

Comment: Note: This answer assumes that the meaning of "overflow" in the question is like a paragraph of text that continues in the next column, and not like a collapsing column (where the first column increases in width to fill the space the other column used to occupy).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine whether there's any content in the right sidebar - you can't do that with pure CSS. However, if you want the central content to spill over anyways, invoke an `overflow` property in your CSS:

```
#left {
    width: 440px;
    float: left;
    overflow-x: visible;
}
```

And if you don't want to wrap text, look into the `white-space` property.

Comment: Nothing has changed using that. Any ideas? The text oveflows but the images don't.

Comment: Have you tried setting the images to `display:inline` and `max-width: 100%; width: 100%`?